# Consulta e impresión de datos sql en php

Tags: php, html, sql

Tengo un problema con la impresión de datos, soy nuevo programando y no se como imprimir datos de otra tabla relacionada.
Mi tabla ya imprime las sucursales pero quiero traer los usuarios que están relacionados a esa sucursal en un apartado abajo pero cuando lo intento me sale este error

Warning: Trying to access array offset on value of type bool in C:\xampp\htdocs\almacen\views\sucursales.php on line 57

```
<?php
                            $item = null;
                            $valor = null;
                            $sucursales = ControladorSucursales::ctrMostrarSucursales($item, $valor);
                            foreach ($sucursales as $key => $value) {
                                $Almacen = $value["Almacen"];
                                $Sucursal = $value["Sucursal"];
                                $Direccion = $value["Direccion"];
                                $Correo = $value["Correo"];
                                $Telefono = $value["Telefono"];
                                $IDSucursal = $value["IDSucursal"];

                                $usuarios = ControladorUsuarios::ctrMostrarUsuarios($IDSucursal, $valor);

                                $Usuario = $usuarios["Nombre"];


                                echo '
                                    <tr data-widget="expandable-table" aria-expanded="false">
                                        <td>' . $Almacen . '</td>
                                        <td>' . $Sucursal . '</td>
                                        <td>' . $Direccion . '</td>
                                        <td>' . $Correo . '</td>
                                        <td>' . $Telefono . '</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr class="expandable-body">
                                        <td colspan="5">
                                            <p>
                                            ' . $Usuario . ' 
                                            </p>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
  ';
                            }
                            ?>
```

Este codigo es de una tabla que estoy haciendo

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Se supone que en el area amarilla tendria que imprimir el usuario de esa sucursal

Este es el controlador de el usuario

```
static public function ctrMostrarUsuarios($item, $valor){

        $tabla = "usuarios";

        $respuesta = ModeloUsuarios::MdlMostrarUsuarios($tabla, $item, $valor);

        return $respuesta;
    }
```

Y este es el modelo

```
class ModeloUsuarios{

   /*=============================================
   MOSTRAR USUARIOS
   =============================================*/

   static public function mdlMostrarUsuarios($tabla, $item, $valor){

       if($item != null){

           $stmt = Conexion::conectar()->prepare("SELECT * FROM $tabla WHERE IDSucursal = :$item");

           $stmt -> bindParam(":".$item, $valor, PDO::PARAM_STR);

           $stmt -> execute();

           return $stmt -> fetch();

       }else{

           $stmt = Conexion::conectar()->prepare("SELECT * FROM $tabla WHERE IDSucursal = :$item");

           $stmt -> execute();

           return $stmt -> fetchAll();

       }
       

       $stmt -> close();

       $stmt = null;

   }
```

Ya intente hacer lo que vi en un curso pero no me sale esta parte, se los agradecería mucho

Comment: Qué hay en la línea 57?

Comment: @DjCrazy $Usuario = $usuarios["Nombre"];

Comment: Revisa qué te está retornando `$usuarios`, al parecer por ahí está el problema... Tal vez no te está retornando un `array`. Puedes usar la función `var_dump($usuarios);` o `print_r($usuarios);` para verificar la información que contiene.

Comment: @DjCrazy me sale bool(false)

Comment: Entonces ahí está el problema... Fíjate que en la vista haces esto: `$Usuario = $usuarios["Nombre"];`, estás tratando de acceder a una posición de un `array` cuando el resultado es de tipo `booleano`. Revisa en tu base de datos si la sucursal existe y si tiene usuarios relacionados.